# How to add a new object into material table by user input?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, html-table, angular-material

I'm trying to create an app that lets me add a new user to a table. The error that I get is:

> "Property 'user' does not exist on type 'BugTableComponent'"

I'm using material templates and there is none that allows me to do precisely what I want it to do. For what I understand the problem is that the existing array is outside the `bugTablecomponent` so it cannot be find. On the other side if I put the array into the component it cannot be "reached" by the table.
What could be a solution to such a problem?

Excuse me for the poorness of my technical language, I'm new to it.

HTML:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="myDataArray" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.userName}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Age</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.age}} </td>
  </ng-container>
  <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay">
  </tr>
  <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let dataSource; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
</mat-table>
<p>
  <mat-form-field apparence="legacy">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="user.userName" type="text" name="newuserName" id="newuserName" class="form-control">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field apparence="legacy">
    <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="user.age" type="text" name="newuserAge" id="newAge" class="form-control">
  </mat-form-field>
</p>`enter code here`
<button mat-button type="button" (click)="addName()">submit</button>
```

TypeScript:

```
export class BugTableComponent {
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ["userName", "age"];
  myDataArray = USER_DATA;

  addName() {
    this.myDataArray.push(this.user);
    this.user = {};
  }
}
let USER_DATA: user[] = [
  { userName: "Wacco", age: 12 },
  { userName: "Wacca", age: 13 },
  { userName: "Waccu", age: 14 }
];

export interface user {
  userName: string;
  age: number;
}
```

Comment: You probably need another object `user: User` to refer interface `User`, so that you can use it else where. You cannot directly refer interface name `User` and access its properties else where. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uyxpy4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @AmitChigadani, just a humble, out of curiosity question. Wiktor has already defined the interface 'user'. Why do you think that defining a new interface 'User' will solve the problem?

Comment: @Shahana Well, I did not ask to create new interface `User`. I mentioned to create a reference or object to that interface called `user: User`. And I refactored the interface name `user` as `User` in my comment as per coding standards. Without creating the interface reference, we cannot access its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MatTableDataSource is immutable array. You need to push the new value in a temporary array then replace the dataSource table with the newly pushed table. Sample Code:

user.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material';

export interface user {
  userName: string;
  age: number;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user',
  templateUrl: './user.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user.component.scss']
})
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ["userName", "age"];
  public USER_DATA: user[] = [
    { userName: "Wacco", age: 12 },
    { userName: "Wacca", age: 13 },
    { userName: "Waccu", age: 14 }
  ];
  public newUser = {userName: "ABC", age: 15};
  public myDataArray: any;

  addName() {
    const newUsersArray = this.USER_DATA;
    newUsersArray.push(this.newUser);
    this.myDataArray = [...newUsersArray];
    this.newUser = {userName:"", age: 0};
    console.warn(this.myDataArray);
  }

  constructor() {
    this.myDataArray = new MatTableDataSource<user>([...this.USER_DATA]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

}
```

User.component.html:

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="myDataArray" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"><div> {{user.userName}} </div></mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Age</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"><div> {{user.age}} </div></mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
  <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
  <mat-row *matRowDef="let dataSource; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
<p>
  <mat-form-field apparence="legacy">
    <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="newUser.userName" type="text" name="newuserName" id="newuserName" class="form-control">
  </mat-form-field>

  <mat-form-field apparence="legacy">
    <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="newUser.age" type="text" name="newuserAge" id="newAge" class="form-control">
  </mat-form-field>
</p>
<button mat-button type="button" (click)="addName()">submit</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my answer.

In .html file

```
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="myDataArray" class="mat-elevation-z8">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
      <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</th>
      <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.userName}} </td>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
     <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Age</th>
     <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"> {{user.age}} </td>
   </ng-container>
   <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
   <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let dataSource; columns: columnsToDisplay"></tr>
</mat-table>
<p>
   <mat-form-field apparence="legacy">
      <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="user.userName" type="text" name="newuserName" id="newuserName" class="form-control">
   </mat-form-field>

   <mat-form-field apparence="legacy">
      <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
      <input matInput [(ngModel)]="user.age" type="text" name="newuserAge" id="newAge" class="form-control">
   </mat-form-field>
</p>`enter code here`
<button mat-button type="button" (click)="addName()">submit</button>
```

In .ts file

```
export class BugTableComponent {
    columnsToDisplay: string[] = ["userName", "age"];
    user = new User();
    userData = User[]= [
        { userName: "Wacco", age: 12 },
        { userName: "Wacca", age: 13 },
        { userName: "Waccu", age: 14 }
    ];
    myDataArray = new MatTableDataSource(this.userData);

    addName() {
       let newUser : User = {
          userName : this.user.userName,
          age : this.user.age
       }
       this.userData.push(newUser);
       this.myDataArray.data = this.userData;
    }
}
```

In user.model.ts

```
export class User {
   userName: string;
   age: number;
}
```

When you click submit button new users will populate in the mat table.

Answer (score 0):

> "Property 'user' does not exist on type 'BugTableComponent'"

This error means exactly what is says - the BugTableComponent class has no property called 'user' and this is obvious in your code sample. You are trying to use the 'user' property (e.g. `this.user`) but you have not declared it. A fix:

```
export class BugTableComponent {

    user: User = {
        userName: null,
        age: null
    };

    columnsToDisplay: string[] = ["userName", "age"];
    myDataArray = USER_DATA;

    addName() {
        this.myDataArray.push(this.user);
        this.user = {
            userName: null,
            age: null
        };
    }
}

let USER_DATA: User[] = [
    { userName: "Wacco", age: 12 },
    { userName: "Wacca", age: 13 },
    { userName: "Waccu", age: 14 }
];

export interface User {
    userName: string;
    age: number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in adding a new object into a material table.

HTML:

```
<table mat-table #table [dataSource]="myDataArray" class="mat-elevation-z8">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="userName">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Name</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"><div> {{user.userName}} </div></mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="age">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Age</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let user"><div> {{user.age}} </div></mat-cell>
      </ng-container>
      
      <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></mat-header-row>
      <mat-row *matRowDef="let dataSource; columns: columnsToDisplay;"></mat-row>
    </table>

<mat-form-field apparence="legacy">
   <mat-label>Name</mat-label>
   <input matInput [(ngModel)]="newUser.userName" type="text" name="newuserName" id="newuserName" class="form-control">
</mat-form-field><br>
          
<mat-form-field apparence="legacy">
    <mat-label>Age</mat-label>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="newUser.age" type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control">
</mat-form-field><br>

<button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="addUser()">submit</button>
```

components.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';


export interface user {
  userName: string;
  age: number;
}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  
  columnsToDisplay: string[] = ["userName", "age"];


    public USER_DATA: user[] = [
        { userName: "Wacco", age: 12 },
        { userName: "Wacca", age: 13 },
        { userName: "Waccu", age: 14 }
  ];
  public newUser = {userName: "ABC", age: 10};
  public myDataArray: any;

  
  addUser() {
    const newUsersArray = this.USER_DATA;
    newUsersArray.push(this.newUser);
    this.myDataArray = [...newUsersArray];// refresh the datasource
    this.newUser = {userName:"", age: 0};
    console.warn(this.myDataArray);
  }

  
  constructor() {
    this.myDataArray = new MatTableDataSource<user>([...this.USER_DATA]);
  }

  ngOnInit() {}


}
```